# Simple experiment proving air pressure is stronger than water pressure at sea level

Tags: pressure, air, home-experiment

I conducted a simple experiment I: pour a little of water into a cup, put a card on top & turn all upside down. The card does not fall $\Rightarrow$
$$P_i + P_w < P_o\tag{1}$$
$P_i$ : air pressure inside the cup forcing down
$P_w$ : water pressure forcing down
$P_o$ : air pressure outside the cup forcing up

After that, I did experiment II: all is the same as experiment I without any water. The card falls $\Rightarrow$
$$P_o \leq  P_i +  P_r\tag{2}$$ 
$P_r$ : air pressure inside the cup forcing down which replaced volume of previous water.

Combining (1) and (2):
\begin{align}
P_i + P_w & < P_o \leq  P_i +  P_r\\
P_w    & <   P_r
\end{align}
which means that the air pressure is stronger than water pressure at sea level.

Experiment III: all is the same as experiment II except that the cup's rim got wet. The card is still held up.

NET CONCLUSION:

1. The card is majorly held up NOT by air pressure, BUT by water's stickiness which is down to water molecule's charge polarization.
2. All scientific explanation in YouTube are basically wrong

Comment: I suspect the card is being held on the glass by capillary forces and you need to consider these as well.

Comment: In its present form (v2), this seems like a [check-my-work question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/44126), which isn't a good fit for us.

Comment: Hi @rob! I am physics fanatic. I have been working, study all ALONE to become a true scientist. So sometimes, I really need objective perspectives from the community. Why don't you just put the judgement aside and join me to enjoy the beauty & mystery of nature?

Comment: Hi @Willy! I don't want to discourage your enthusiasm, but [our policy on homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) has a pretty strong community consensus. There *are* some folks who discuss this sort of thing occasionally in [chat], if you would like to try that venue for the sorts of questions you've been asking. If you keep reading on the site you'll start to develop a sense of what questions are a good fit and what aren't. See you around!

Answer (score 1):

Water pressure in your experiment when the cup is overturned is equal to the weight of the water in the cup, divided by the area of the top of the cup.  [It turns out that the height of the cup would need to be nearly 34 feet for the water pressure to equal the air pressure at sea level.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure)  So you are right that, in your experiment, the water pressure is less than the air pressure.  Note that the wetness of the water creates a seal around the card/cup interface, which prevents air from entering the inverted cup.

Comment: Hi @McGrew. Thank you! Please check my third experiment above out.

Comment: The card's weight is very small.  You could try some variations on your experiment: poke a small hole in the middle of the card and see if it falls.  Do the same, but attach a weight to a thread that is threaded through the hole and terminated by a button; see how much weight can be supported by the card in arrangements I, Ii, and III.

Comment: From III => equation: $P_i$ + G =  $P_o$ + F.             
$P_i$ : air pressure inside cup force down.                                                 
$P_o$ : air pressure outside cup force up.                                                         G: gravity force pull down.                                                                                  F: electric force from water rim pull up                                                         Case1: use heavy plate: $P_i$ + G > $P_o$ + F=> plate fall(G increase)   Case2: poke a hole: $P_i$ + G > $P_o$ + F=> plate fall($P_i$> $P_o$)